# NSBezierPath setLineDash doesn't produce any effect

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, graphics

As the title says, `setLineDash` applied to my `NSBezierPath` doesn't change the stroked line. No effect at all.

I expect it to make my line dashed. See two vertical red lines on the picture.

Code:

```
NSBezierPath* p= [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
CGFloat x = r.origin.x + r.size.width/2;

float dash_pattern[]={15.,15.};
NSInteger count = sizeof(dash_pattern)/sizeof(dash_pattern[0]);
[p setLineDash:(CGFloat*)dash_pattern count:count phase:0.]; // no effect ?

[p moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(x, r.origin.y+r.size.height)];
[p lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(x, [view bounds].origin.y+[view bounds].size.height)];
[[NSColor redColor]set];

[p stroke];
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but on 64-bit OS X, `CGFloat` is a `double` and not a `float`. You should therefore define the array as

```
CGFloat dash_pattern[]={15.,15.};
```

This also makes the explicit cast in `setLineDash:(CGFloat*)dash_pattern` unnecessary.

Comment: HOLY CRAP. THAT WORKED.

Comment: You've saved my day,dude!